# How can I get my login function to work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I'm trying to build a working login function that will take me to my menu.
Here is the code I have:

```
def login(userlist):
    verified = False
    name = input('username: ')
    password = input('password: ')
    while not verified:
        name = input('username: ')
        password = input('password: ')
        if [name, password] in userlist:
            verified = True
            print('You logged in the system!')
        else:
            print('invalid username\password.')
    return verified
```

Even though I type in the correct username and password into the program, it keeps saying Invalid...
What am I missing? Also, userlist is a textfile with the usernames and passwords are separated by lines. I'm able to read the file because of my load function:

```
def load():
    user_file = open('userdata.txt', 'r')
    userlist = []
    line = user_file.readline()
    while line != '':
        line = line.split()
        userlist.append(line)
        line = user_file.readline()
    user_file.close()
    return userlist

    My text file ends up looking like this:
```

## username #password #list

## Sam #password #[1,2,...]

(the list of numbers doesn't actually spill over to the next line)
Here is my registration function, which I think is relevant.

```
 def register(userlist):
# ASK FOR USERNAME
name = input('Choose your username: ')
while search(userlist, name):
    print('The username is not available. Choose somethng else. ')
    name = input('Choose your username: ')
# ASKING FOR PASSWORD
password = input('Choose your password: ')
p = input('Retype your password:  ')
while p != password:
    password = input('Choose your password: ')
    p = input('Retype your password: ')

# SURVEY INDEX

a = list(range(26))
user = [name, p, a]
userlist.append(user)
print('Your registration is successful, your user namw ia: ', name)
user_file = open('userdata.txt', 'a')
user_file.write(str(name) + '   ' + str(p) + '  ' + str(a)+ '\n')
user_file.close()

return userlist
```

Comment: What is `userlist`? `dict`, `list of list`, etc.?

Comment: userlist is a text filethat looks like this:  
Hunter   password1                                                                                                          Charles password

Comment: How do you read it in?

Comment: I have a load function that returns the userlist                                                     load():
 user_file = open('userdata.txt', 'r')
 userlist = []
 line = user_file.readline()
 while line != '':
  line = line.split()
  userlist.append(line)
  line = user_file.read()
 user_file.close()

 return userlist

Comment: Ok, I already had that on there, I just forgot to type it in

Comment: syntax, I am unable to reproduce your error.  Are you sure your 'userdata.txt' file is correct?

Comment: I figured out that the problem has something to do with my registration function. The login works fine when I have a user register only one username and one password but when I add a survey as part of the process that saves the data into a list next to each users password, it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

if userlist is file IO object:

```
for i in userlist.readlines():
    if [name, password] in i.split()  # assumes no whitespace in password is allowed
        verified = True
        print('You logged in the system!')
```

if `userlist` is a dict:

```
if (name,password) in userlist.items()
```

Comment: userlist is a text file that contains each users user name and password on a separite line

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your load function. When you checked if `[name, password]` were in the userlist you hadn't stored the username and password together, they were in separate lists in the userlist.

So I changed the load function to do what you wanted.
I changed the load function though assuming your text file looks like this (missing line breaks is fine as well).

**EDIT:** Okay so I made changes to my answer now I know what your text file looks like.

```
def login(userlist):
    verified = False
    print(userlist)
    while not verified:
        name = input('username: ')
        password = input('password: ')
        if [name, password] in userlist:
            verified = True
            print('You logged in the system!')
        else:
            print('invalid username\password.')
    return verified

def load():
    userlist = []
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as user_file:
        for line in user_file:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
            userlist.append(line.split()[:2]) # Gets only name and password
    return userlist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_list = load()
    login(user_list)
```

If you would like to change to a dictionary, instead then you can do this

`if [name, password] in userlist:` becomes `if userlist.get(name) == password:`

`userlist = []` becomes `userlist = {}`

`userlist.append(line.split()[:2])` becomes

```
name, password = line.split()[:2]
userlist[name] = password
```

**Side Note:**
I would suggest changing your write line to something cleaner.

```
user_file.write("{0} {1} {2}\n".format(name, p, a))
```